# How to upload multiple files using selenium without the upload popup dialog?

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests

I'm using **Selenium webdriver** to write an automation testing tool in `Java`.

This tool will run on a **headless server** via **Jenkins** call. My problem is to handle **multiple files upload**. Selenium **can not** open browser, so that when I click on upload button on website, **the select files popup** also **not appear**.

I'm wondering if there are any other solutions for me to handle the **upload multi files** during automate testing.

P.S. I can handle single file upload using `sendkeys` function. But I can not do that to handle multiple files upload.

P.P.S I can not using **AutoIT** or **`Robot`** class to handle the popup dialog (because there is no popup dialog because of headless server)

Comment: Have you tried to make a String like `C:.../f1 \n C:.../f2` and use sendkeys? Put a new line `\n` after every file.

Comment: Relevant _HTML_ and _code trials_?

Comment: @raul1ro I tried your suggestion and it's working now, you should post an answer for me to accept to help others with same problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a String which contain all paths of files

```
String pathf1 = "...\f1.txt";
String pathf2 = "...\f2.txt";
String pathf3 = "...\f3.txt";
String allF = pathf1 + " \n " + pathf2 + " \n " + pathf3;
```

And send this String with `sendKeys(allF);` to your `<input>`.

I tested on `ChromeDriver` with an `<input type = "file" multiple>` and for me worked.

Comment: What about if a website doesn't contain an `<input type="file">` element and has a custom upload dialog?

Comment: @AaronFranke, There should be an `input file` in code, even if it's not visible. Or for some websites it appears after you interact with some elements. But I suggest to open a question if you have difficulties